# PHP Select in mysql database with unknown and operators

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-normalization

I have a database of books. There is a Tag field that contains multiple tags and the number of tags isn't the same. So we have something like that in two rows:

comics,history

art,science,tag3,tag4

Now I have a string like `$stringtosearch` which can be any combinations of tags with that structure.

tag1,tag2... (it is with comma and I don't know the number of tags or commas...).

So how should I write the select query for that search?

NOTE: I want for example if user searches a string that contains  2 tags ,display records which has all two tags and not only one of them

Comment: Simple. See normalisation.

Comment: how many rows of this stuff shall I nicely call it at this point ? How many is So many :<

Comment: @drew Pierce So many rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Like` keyword here.

```
SELECT * from tst where tags like '%t1%' AND tags like '%t2';
```

SQL Fiddle :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3e6c/2

Comment: this is a perfect example of why you don't want your data saved this way to begin with :<   ... could basically rule out the use of indexes and usher in the dreaded Table Scan